# Downloading website via wget only yields index page

Tags: wget

a friend has asked me to make some small modifications to a website for him. I'm familiar with HTML & CSS, but turned to wget as an initial way to accelerate the process.

Right now, only the index page is downloading (for this website: http://www.controlreps.com/).

Here's the script as well:

```
wget --wait=2 --level=inf --limit-rate=20K --recursive --page-requisites --user-agent=Mozilla --no-parent --convert-links --adjust-extension --no-clobber -e robots=off https://examples.com
```

Also, it should be noted that I was able to successfully implement the script on a different site. So is there something blocking it on this site? I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to `DDOS` this website? Could be the case if too much people try to.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) SE site. This site appears to be hosted at hostgator.com, and built with websitebuilder.com. Does the same apply to the site where your script works? Are the index pages of both sites similar?